# call view controller segue from within tableView delegate class

Tags: ios, delegates, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have separated my tableView delegate and data source from the tableView controller. so far its working great. however, I have now come to a place where I need to implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method. When this method is called I need to perform a segue from my view controller, but I dont have a reference to the view controller from inside the delegate class to call the method like [myViewController performSegueWithIdentifier...

Whats the proper way to handle this? Do I just add a property to my delegate to store the view controller? That does not seem like a good idea since the view controller has a reference to the delegate already. How can I reference back the VC? I was thinking I could post a notification but there has to be a better way than that. Ive always just used the view controller as the delegate so I have never had to deal with this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems strange to me because if you create the segue in storyboard, say a push segue from a tableView cell to another viewcontroller, then when the tableview cell is tapped the segue is automatically triggered. You can do other things in

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender
```

as for

> add a property to my delegate to store the view controller

It's ok. Because

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id< UITableViewDelegate > delegate
```

viewcontroller doesn't retain the delegate

Comment: if you use a segue from a cell to another VC, then you cant use didSelectRowAtIndexPath because that gets called after prepareForSegue. Initially I had set the segue up as a manual segue, which is why I needed to call performSegueWithidentifier from within didSelectRowAtIndexPath of my delegate. However I ended up doing it your way and changing the segue to be from the cell to the VC, and then just using prepareForSegue and using self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row to index my data source. so in the end you were right, I didnt need any of what I thought I did. thanks